# performance of apps compiled in java 1.6 and run under 1.7 jvm

Tags: java, performance

I have project which is compiled with java 1.6, but it is run on machine with 1.7 jvm and I'm wondering if there would be performance improvement if the project would also be compiled with java 1.7.

Comment: You could refer to this blog to get insight about the performance between 1.6 and 1.7: http://lingpipe-blog.com/2009/03/30/jdk-7-twice-as-fast-as-jdk-6-for-arrays-and-arithmetic/                                                                                     


And this: http://geeknizer.com/java-7-whats-new-performance-benchmark-1-5-1-6-1-7/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Note: I'm speaking here of the Oracle JDK and JVM.)

If you mean simply recompiling the source files without taking advantage of any of the new features in Java 7, I doubt you'd see any significant change in performance.

Performance optimization is done:

- By the compiler optimizing the bytecode, and
- By the JVM, optimizing as it runs, in particular optimizing "hot spots" (hence the name of the JVM, HotSpot) as it detects them

So if you're not using new Java 7 features, the only improvement you'd see would be if there were some significant new bytecode-level optimization that the Java 7 compiler does that the Java 6 compiler didn't do. I don't see any listed in the [release notes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jdk7-relnotes-418459.html), and even by Java 6, the compiler was quite well optimized (and frankly, I think most of the optimization happens in the JVM anyway; there were performance improvements in JVM 7 that you're already getting the benefit of).

The JVM isn't having to do any significant working around of changes to the class file format, either. According to the [Java SE 7 and JDK 7 Compatibility page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-417013.html), The only binary compatibility change was that the minor version number changed because of the introduction of a new bytecode. But that bytecode (`invokedynamic`) supports features that won't be in your Java 6 source code, so nothing to see there. The structure didn't change, just the minor version number.

Answer (score -2):

A quick way is that you should follow http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jdk7-relnotes-418459.html to check if your projects use those performance enhancements in JDK 1.7, right?

Comment: This does not answer the question if the project must be compiled with java 1.7

Comment: No need to compile with JDK1.7 because the focus should be the runtime env itself.